# MongoDB: Collection named "createCollection" how to drop it?

Tags: mongodb

By mistake I named it "createCollection" and now when I try to drop this collection it says

> `[thread1] TypeError: db.createCollection.drop is not a function :
>   @(shell):1:1`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection("createCollection").drop()`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name a collection like a keyword, you cant directly use it like `db.collectionName`. Instead, you have to first retrive the collection with `getCollection` and call the method on the returned object.

```
db.getCollection('createCollection').drop()
```

That's also the way to go, if you want to query a GridFS table directly.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName.chunks').find()
```